# css responsive width creating extra space in right margin

Tags: css, html, wordpress, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a site with responsive css, with media queries at 768px, 480px, and 320px.  When I resize below 1040px, same extra space appears on the right margin of the entire page and I can't figure out where this is coming from.  This is for a WordPress site. Here's the [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/schatzkin/gcrL5jds/).

Here's some of the relevant css:

```
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: -.01em;
}
body {
  font-family: "ff-dagny-web-pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: black;
}
#main {
  margin: 0 15%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #main {
    margin: 0 10% 0 10%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #main {
    margin: 0 5% 0 5%;
  }
}
#content {
  float: left;
  width: 68%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cannot see the margin on the right side of the page. Could you specify which element/tag has the margin?

Comment: Extra space is coming from `<div class="form-search">`, try adding responsive css to that as well.

Comment: hey artm, good catch. Now it seems so obvious.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Then check the "form-search" class of the style. Wondering what's the design should look like? Cause we know now it has the margin right, but what it should look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the offending object, width was a div buried in the middle of the page (social-icons) that wasn't being resize for smaller viewports.  Thanks to everyone who helped keep me focused.

Comment: Great work solving your own problem. Please set your question to Answered.

Answer (score 0):

Check your css on `.form-search`. You have a fixed pixel width of `219px` with a `margin-left` of `80%`.

```
.form-search {
  height: 14px;
  width: 219px;
  margin: 0em 0px 0px 80%;
  padding: 1em 0px 0px;
}
```

Combining a pixel width with a percentage margin is a sure way to create an element wider than 100%.

Have you tried using the web inspector? It's an integral part of web debugging, I would highly suggesting learning to use a web inspector so you can find these types of issues yourself (Stack Overflow is not a debugging engine).

Comment: Thanks Christian, I really appreciate your help.  I am using Firebug but for some reason just couldn't see this one.

Comment: Okay, I've taken out the % margin but I am still getting a wide right margin, especially for devices < 480px wide.  On 320px wide, the site just takes up 1/2 the device width.

Comment: I could go and debug it for you (again), but then you wouldn't learn anything. You need to go through every element and figure out which one is causing you problems. Try deleting elements with the inspector until the margin disappears. You'll soon figure out the offending element, then you'll be able to inspect the properties to determine the issue.

Comment: Yes, yes, of course you're right, I just needed a little push.